# Parse error in the solidity solution needed

Tags: solidity

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.7.1;
contract A {
    mapping(uint => uint) public objects;

    function B()  returns {
        objects[0] = 42;
    }
}

contract B {
    // insert address of deployed First here
    A a = A(0x692a70d2e424a56d2c6c27aa97d1a86395877b3a);

    function get() returns(uint) {
        return a.objects(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, could you please provide an explanation of what kind of issue you are having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue in your case, is that you're omitting the modifier access in your functions `B` and `get()` and other syntax issues.
I adjusted your smart contract in this way and I put some notes:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.7.1;

contract A {
    mapping(uint => uint) public objects;

    // NOTE: I declare a setter() function that allows you to set a specific value
    //       in a specific mapping key
    function setObject(uint _id) public {
        objects[_id] = 42;
    }
}

contract B {
    A a;

    // NOTE: Inside smart contract constructor, I instanced the smart contract a with 
    //       address that passed in input
    constructor(address aAddress) {
        a = A(aAddress);
    }

    function get() external view returns(uint) {
        return a.objects(0);
    }
}
```

**REMEMBER**: Before deploy `A` smart contract, copy its address and then deploy `B` smart contract passing inside it the address copied previously. Then call `setObject ()` passing an _id (in this case 0) and then call `get()` method to retrieve and print a value related to key with value 0.